# Instantiate a class when only class name is known

Tags: java, reflection

Is it possible to instantiate a class if only class name is known and the class does not have a default constructor?

Only class name is available but nothing is known about the constructors (how many arguments, what type of arguments).

I googled and according to my research, it looks like it is not possible.

But I am just asking this question here to know whether my understanding is correct or is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

This is a rough example but should get you started. This will work so long as the class has a constructor with parameters that themselves have a valid no args constructor. In the example below, the class ToBeLoaded only has a one String argument constructor. That constructor is called and it should print Value is: [] to the console. The reason is that we're calling the no args constructor in String which returns an empty String.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Parameter;

public class ClassForNameTest {
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, InvocationTargetException {
        Class<?> tblClass = Class.forName("ToBeLoaded");

        Constructor[] constructors = tblClass.getConstructors();

        for (Constructor constructor : constructors) {
            boolean canCallConstructor = true;
            Parameter[] parameters = constructor.getParameters();
            Object[] arguments = new Object[parameters.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
                Parameter parameter = parameters[i];

                Constructor[] parameterConstructors = parameter.getType().getConstructors();

                Constructor noArgsConstructor = null;
                for (Constructor parameterConstructor : parameterConstructors) {
                    if (parameterConstructor.getParameters().length == 0) {
                        noArgsConstructor = parameterConstructor;
                    }
                }

                if (noArgsConstructor == null) {
                    canCallConstructor = false;
                } else {
                    Object arg = noArgsConstructor.newInstance(new Object[]{});
                    arguments[i] = arg;
                }
            }

            if (canCallConstructor) {
                ToBeLoaded tbl = (ToBeLoaded) constructor.newInstance(arguments);
                System.out.println("Value is: [" + tbl.value + "]");
            }
        }
    }
}

class ToBeLoaded {
    public String value;

    public ToBeLoaded(String arg) {
        this.value = arg;
    }
}
```